# Clonezilla does not carry over user login configuration in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, clone, clonezilla

I have a machine with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 installed. There is a single user and the user is set to login automatically without asking for password. I took device image with Clonezilla to restore the same image to multiple other devices.

I tested 4 "identical" setups. By identical I mean they are the same intel NUC-like devices from the same manufacturer and part number. 3 of them are working as expected. The restored image successfully boots into user desktop and all my modifications are there.

However, the other device keeps asking for user password.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: Check the system logs.